# org-export subtree to filename.pdf with EXPORT_FILE_NAME fails

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm trying to export subtrees using `#+PROPERTY: EXPORT_FILE_NAME filename` as described in the Org manual at bottom [here.](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html)

I have a test file called `test.org`:

```
* This Is A Test
  #+PROPERTY: EXPORT_FILE_NAME export-test
  here is some content
* This Is Another Test
  #+PROPERTY: EXPORT_FILE_NAME another-export-test
  here is some more content.
```

When I put point on either `* heading` and export with `C-c C-e C-s l o` the resulting PDF file has the correct content, but is not called "export-test" or "another-export-test" but instead "test.pdf". I'm a beginner at this, and can't fathom what I'm doing wrong.

Org 8.3.1

Emacs 24.5.1

Comment: Hi Steven, you probably took the wrong property name from me, please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try it with property drawers:

```
* This Is A Test 
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: export-test
:END:
```

Then put the cursor on this headline and export explicitly only above tree with `C-c C-e C-s l o`

Comment: Apologies, that was a mistake in my question but not in my approach, and thank you for catching it. I've fixed it in the post---the problem includes me using using `C-c C-e C-s l o`

Comment: Then it seems just to be working with a proper PROPERTY drawer. Please update your question and I will update my answer. ;-)

Comment: I gave this a try, but am still experiencing the same result. I wonder if it could be a bug? I'm new enough to emacs that I've never seen a bug before .. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I've put the wrong property name into my example.  With the right one - I updated - it is working under Emacs-24.5 with org-mode 8.2.10.

Comment: That did it---thank you for your help! This will be a huge aid to me this week.

Comment: Does not work on Emacs 26.1 and Orgmode 9.0.9. Copied your answer and pasted in an org file, then ran C-c C-e l l to export to a latex file. No sucess. Any ideas?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: Could you please be more specific, how can one know your system?  For example: What is the error message, which OS are using, do you have TeX installed, can you export other org files to TeX, ...

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm hey, sorry about that. I can export org files to TeX without any issues. When I add the properties drawer with the `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` to a subtree, select it and export it, I don't get any errors. The file is successfully exported with the default name. I'm on Mac High Sierra and have Mactex 2017 installed.

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: No problem. Did put the cursor to the headline of this subtree and then translate explicitly only the subtree in question? With C-c C-e C-s ll?  How can you otherwise "select" it?

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm I am not sure what you mean by translating explicitly the subtree. What I usually do is "select" a subtree with C-spacebar, and while it is marked, hit C-c C-e l l. This exports the subtree to a tex file. I noticed that **it does work with C-c C-e C-s** (changing from buffer to subtree). I had never use that option before, but thanks for suggesting it. Do you know what differs?

Comment: @GuilhermeSalomé: The difference is that when not using C-s the whole buffer (file) will be exported and the property for the file name is not used! ;-)  With C-s org-mode is exporting only the current (sub)-tree and only then the respective tree properties are effective.